# Fresh Cyanogenmod install, location doesn't work

Tags: cyanogenmod, geolocation

Yesterday I installed Cyanogenmod using the one click install on my Nexus 4.

There is a little problem though: when using location in the battery saving mode, when it only uses cell and wifi signals to guess your position, it simply can't locate. Using GPS is fine, it locks position within seconds, but it's too battery hungry, kills my phone in a few hours.

Is this a known thing? Can it be fixed?

EDIT: After 2 days, location in power saving mode comes and goes.

Comment: What version of Cyanogenmod do you have? And do you have the Google apps (Gmail etc.)?

Comment: Latest One CLick installer version (11.0-InstallerXNPQ02R). I have all Google apps installed, the installer did it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using cyanogenmod 11, then the issues your having are very common. Its still under development so there are things that don't work. Some of the times something works, but then is broken again in the next release. Right now your best option would be to either flash cyanogenmod 10.2 or just bear with it and wait for a release that fixes the issue.